# How to filter a JSON page feeding data to Select2?

Tags: php, jquery, json, sql-server, jquery-select2

I'm trying to populate a Select2 box with data from a t-sql query. The query is run on a PHP page which translates the output to JSON and is called in the javascript of the main page.

The main page looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require('db.php');      // Bring in the database connection
include("auth.php");    // Make sure the user is logged in to an account

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" http-equiv="Content Type" charset="utf-8"/>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SELECT 2 -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <body style="background-color: #F5F5F5;">

        <select class="js-data-example-ajax">
        </select>

        <script>
        $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
            width: '250px',
            ajax: {
                url: 'http://10.1.248.41/TFM-Project/ImportINjson.php',
                dataType: 'json'
                // Additional AJAX parameters go here
          }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JSON page looks like this:

```
<?php
require('db.php');      // Bring in the database connection
include("auth.php");    // Make sure the user is logged in to an account

$search = $_GET['search'];

//JSON Table Stuff
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [IN] AS id, Nom as text
        FROM dbo.[TFM_NumérosIN2012]
        ;";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

do {
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

$data2 = json_encode($result);

echo '{ "results":' . $data2 . '}';

?>
```

The data output by the JSON page looks like this:

```
{ "results":[{"id":2,"text":"SMITH Sean"},{"id":3,"text":"CHARLES charley"},{"id":4,"text":"TFC Madrid"},{"id":5,"text":"VAN DAMME jean claude"}]}
```

The data is loading into the select list without any problems. However, I've tried to filter the data multiple ways and nothing has worked. I've tried adding a data parameter and passing a search variable to the php/JSON page and referencing in the $sql variable as a where clause, but this doesn't return anything

To try and filter the data I changed the javascript to this:

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
          width: '250px',
          ajax: {
            url: 'http://10.1.248.41/TFM-Project/ImportINjson.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
              var query = {
                search: params.term
              }

              // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
              return query;
            }
          }
        });
```

But this breaks my select and and it displays a message 'The results could not be loaded.'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers,

Comment: try adding `"pagination": {"more": false}` to the json response, according to the documentation, select2 is expecting it.. like this: `{ "results":[{"id":2,"text":"SMITH Sean"},{"id":3,"text":"CHARLES charley"},{"id":4,"text":"TFC Madrid"},{"id":5,"text":"VAN DAMME jean claude"}],"pagination": {"more": false}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your php file just echo the following line :

```
 echo json_encode($result);
```

In your html/js file :

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js'></script>
<select name='js-data-example-ajax' class='js-data-example-ajax'></select>

$(document).ready(function()
{


$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
      placeholder: "Search for product",
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      width: '250px',
      ajax: {
        url: 'http://10.1.248.41/TFM-Project/ImportINjson.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            var query = {
            search: params.term,
            type: 'public'
          }
          console.log("query : "+query.search);
          return query;
       },
       processResults: function (response) {
        console.log("response : "+response);
          return {
            results: $.map(response, function(obj) {
              console.log("response obj.id: "+obj.id);
              console.log("response obj.text: "+obj.text);
              return { id: obj.id, text: obj.text };
            })
        };
      },
       cache: false
     }
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried this. The data still loads correctly into the select list, however, I am still unable to filter the results. I type my search into the textbox but the data doesn't change at all

Comment: Could you please copy/paste my code into your project and tell me what you get for the console.log ?

Comment: Got it. I had used $_GET instead of $_REQUEST to get the search variable. Thanks  for spending the time to help me with this. There weren't any errors in the log, just nothing was getting passed into the WHERE clause because I am dumb :-(

Comment: I would say : « We are on the way to become smarter »  :-)